# MySQLdb Python write/read methods

Tags: python, mysql-python

I worked a little with MySQLDB in Python and thought I understood how it works.
But now I want to define my own method to be more flexible. Read the code....

```py
import MySQLdb as mydb

class DB(object):
    def read(self, slct, frm):
        connection = mydb.connect("123.12.34.56", "user", "pass", "foo")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s", (slct, frm))
        print cursor.fetchall()

        connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DB()
    db.read("*", "bar")
```

This throws me a SQL Syntax Error. Why can't I use it this way?

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''bar'' at line 1")

Comment: Printing the error will be helpful...

Comment: sorry, I edited it wrong. Now its correct.

Comment: Are you sure you have `bar` table inside `foo` db?

Comment: yes I am sure. ``cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bar")`` works...

Comment: @Tim +1! I had no idea!

Comment: Everyday I learn something new. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about mysqldb, but usually (atleast in pyodbc and sqlite) you cannot parametrize columns or the table name, only values. You can use Python's string formatting for the * and table name part, and use parameters for the rest. For example:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT {col} FROM {table} WHERE foo=%s'.format(col='*', table='bar'), ('my value',))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo -

```
cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s"%(slct, frm))
```